# Python splitting issues due to extra columns being created

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, split, strip, data-cleaning

This is for a project I'm working on.
Using python, I've imported a big CSV file that has about 2000 rows, I turned it into a list.

below is the script that I used to create a list

```
data=[] #Will put the data in here

with open('output.csv', "r") as file: # open the file
for data_row in file: 
#get data one row at a time split up the row into columns, stripping 
whitespace from each one and store it in 'data'
data.append( [x.strip() for x in data_row.split(",")] )
```

My main goal with this project is to create a table directly into a SQL server using a python script using pandas for example 
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns = ['column1' , 'column2', ...]

However, I ran into a problem while splitting because there are fields that contain peoples' names in 'Doe, John' format which creates extra columns and because of that when I insert column names into the pd.DataFrame it throws me error of 'AssertionError: 39 columns passed, passed data had 44 columns'

Could someone please help me solve this problem? I'd appreciate it much!

Comment: When you insert into sql server you can trim the trailing and leading spaces, though i'm certain Python has a similar function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment scsimon. Are you referring to a SQL server's own function? I'm relying on Python solely in terms of connecting to the sql server and inserting the table..

Comment: Correct, to strip the spaces, after you slit on the comma, you can use `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`

Comment: Try changing delimiter character to something unlikely to be in your data when you export, so comma is not the separator. Sometimes tabs work well. Sometimes pipe symbol works well | etc

Comment: Thanks for your comment JGFMK. Are you referring to the delimiter in the original CSV file? the reason why i'm splitting by comma is because the data in CSV is already having the comma as delimiter when I import it to python.